# Dockerfile: OSError: No Default Input Device Available Python

Tags: python, docker, speech-recognition

I have seen this error around, but I have not found a situation that uses Dockerfile to detect input audio device. I am using Flask to run it with the following function

```python
r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    logger.info("Speak")
    audio = r.listen(source)
try:
    logger.info("You said " + r.recognize_google(audio))
except sr.UnknownValueError:
    logger.info("Could not understand audio")
except sr.RequestError as e:
    logger.info("Could not request results; {0}".format(e))
```

This my Dockerfile

```sh
FROM python
WORKDIR /usr/app 
COPY . .
USER root
RUN useradd -u 8877 nonroot
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install libportaudio2 libportaudiocpp0 portaudio19-dev libsndfile1-dev -y \
    && pip3 install pyaudio \
    && pip install -r requirement.txt 
RUN chmod 755 /usr/app/start.sh
USER nonroot
ENTRYPOINT /usr/app/start.sh
```

Comment: What's the actual error you're getting?  How are you running the container?  Generally it's difficult for container processes to access hardware devices; does this application need to run in Docker, or would it make more sense to run it directly on the host?

Comment: The error is  OSError: No Default Input Device Available. Yes because I would be hosting on digital ocean and it would be easier using Docker

Comment: This doesn't seem like the kind of application you could run on a remote hosted system.  You'd be hearing the audio from DO's machine room, not your local system or the end user's desktop machine.

Comment: So no alternative? I know JavaScript uses speech recognition API, but it only works for chrome